# How to import Turkish and Chinese characters into SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have a database table with translations in different Languages. I'm trying to insert chinese and Turkish char with a C# program. But it doesn't seem to be working. I changed the collation of my database to Chinese_PRC_90_CI_AS now the import works for Chinese, but not for Turkish.

But I don't want to be changing the Collation everytime I upload a new language is there a way to resolve this in my code. I'm Reading a excel file -> build insert query(with parameters(@col1,@col2,..)) -> Execute -> Result: b?lüm in database.

Can somebody please help me?

Phoenix

Comment: I have never done it but I believe you can collate differently on different columns in SQL Server.  Then you could do your insertion for the different languages into the different columns independently in your code.  MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem.

I had a problem with my import routine.
I had Nvarchar database fields but when import with parameters I used Char database type instead of NChar.